# Microsoft Word 2003 Headings - Why do some say "do not use"?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003, headers

I am using Microsoft Word 2003 and wanted to use Headings 4 and 5, but why does it say DoNotUse?? Is this some sort of Microsoft joke? Any ideas? 
[image: Headings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not there by default.  Someone has set up your default template to include styles named "DoNotUse".